# is adding ChangeNotifierProvider Widget as Parent of MaterialApp a Flutter Best Practice?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier-provider

Can I using the ChangeNotifierProvider on the top of my app tree? is it a good practice in Flutter?

Also running the MyApp Widget as Stateful widget is a good practice?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    PushNotificationService.messageStream.listen((message) {
      //some code
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => MyProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        //more code
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Its better to priority to use `StatelessWidget` in all flutter App. but also when you need to have a initial state, or local state variable, its will be better to use `StatefullWidget`. So... use as you need.

---

- I would said that using `ChangeNotifierProvider` on top of tree is a common practice.

see here **official example** from docs.flutter.dev, they put inside main function.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CartModel(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

##### ;TLDR

the things that we have to avoid while using provider is with the `Consumer` at the top of widget tree.

read here : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#consumer

> It is best practice to put your Consumer widgets as deep in the tree
> as possible. You don’t want to rebuild large portions of the UI just
> because some detail somewhere changed.

when we called the `notifyListeners();` this will rebuild current `Consumer` widget. when you use it on Top of tree, everytime receive notifylistener your widget Tree will rebuild from the Consumer below.

You can see the example here : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#consumer